# Subtracting two dates with a submit button

Tags: javascript, date, event-listener, subtraction

I have a problem with subtracting two dates. It all start with two inputs. One is for date and one is submit button. On paragraph `#ekran` it needs to show if `datePicked` is lower than today's date. it will show that we need to pick some date in future. Otherwise it will count difference between today's date and some date that we pick.

When I do like this it says its `NaN`. I know i messed up somewhere but I don't know where it is. Probably at `var d = newDate()` that needs to get date formatted correctly. Or I`m wrong? Help me guys.

p.s. It needs to be done in DOM lvl 2 way with eventListener.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="date">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">

    <p id="ekran"></p>


    <script>
     var button = document.querySelector("[type=submit]").addEventListener('click', racunaj);

     function racunaj() {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setDate(30,9,2018);
        var datePicked = document.querySelector("[type=date]").value;

        var diff = document.getElementById("ekran").innerHTML = datePicked;




        if (datePicked< d) {
            "The Picked date need to be bigger then todays date";
        } else {
            return diff;
        }
     }
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `  "The Picked date need to be bigger then todays date";` so you defined a string, did not display it, nor set it to a variable.... what is that supposed to do?

Comment: Next you are comparing a date to a string.

Comment: I forgot to menion after .innerHTML it goes innerHTML = datePicked - d...But i get NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like this (this is my prev answer which i summed up it to increasing the similarities with your code):

```
 window.onload=function(){
    document.querySelector("[type='submit']").addEventListener('click', racunaj); 
   function racunaj() {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setDate(30,9,2018);
        var datePicked = new Date(document.querySelector("[type=date]").value); 
        var diff = datePicked.getTime()-d.getTime();
        document.getElementById("ekran").innerHTML=diff<0 ? "The Picked date need to be bigger then todays date" : diff +" (days: "+(diff/1000/60/60/24).toFixed(2)+")";
        return diff;
     }
}
```

You can check the result [online!](https://jsbin.com/ziyunuhona/edit?output)

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna compare if something is more or less than something else, you have to first make them the same type.

A javascript Date object has a built in function called "getTime()", this can be used to convert a date to a number. 
Once you have two numbers its easy to compare the two.

I rewrote your script to demonstrate this.

```
    var button = document.querySelector("[type=submit]").addEventListener('click', racunaj);

     function racunaj() {
//       first I make the two variables into a number that can be compared

       var currentTimeAndDate = new Date().getTime();
        var datePicked = new Date(document.getElementById("myDate").value).getTime();

// as you see on the console, they are now two numbers that can be compared.      

       console.log(datePicked, currentTimeAndDate)

//then you just do your logic and output different stuff. 

       if(datePicked < currentTimeAndDate){
       var diff = document.getElementById("ekran").innerHTML = "you chose past" 
      }
       else if(datePicked > currentTimeAndDate){
       var diff = document.getElementById("ekran").innerHTML = "you chose future"          
       }
       else{
        var diff = document.getElementById("ekran").innerHTML = "you did not choose" 
       }
     }
```

Here is a codepen: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJEGme?editors=1011

Comment: There is also the corner case of what you want your logic to do if you choose the same date as today. The input will return todays date as 00:00:00 past midnight, and then the currentDateAndTime will be greater since time has elapsed since midnight. This might be exactly what you want...or maybe not...Then you have to manually implement som logic to catch this or avoid it.

Comment: Ty guys, I solved a problem ! Yea I just needed 2 numbers so I can compare.